# Load vector layer with QgsVectorLayer using MSSQL by select statment

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I want to read a layer from a database. I would like to access the table via a select statment.
In PostgeSQL works both:

```
vlp1='.....table="mytable" (geom)'
QgsVectorLayer(vlp1, LayerName , "postgres")
vlp2='.....table="(select * from mytable)" (geom)'
QgsVectorLayer(vlp2, LayerName , "postgres")
```

With MSSQL, only the direct specification of a table works:

```
vlp1='.....table="mytable" (geom)'
QgsVectorLayer(vlp1, LayerName , "mssql")
```

.

**The select statement does not work:**

```
vlp2='.....table="(select * from mytable)" (geom)'
QgsVectorLayer(vlp2, LayerName , "mssql")
```

**Is the MSSQL Select statement not supported?**